# Import existing modules in the VS code plugin extension

Tags: node-modules, vscode-extensions

We're developing a VS Code extensions web plugin using Typescript. We already have a company provided component, which is downloaded in the node_modules folder. But when I'm referring those modules, the application does not start:

[image]

How can I use those components in my plugin extension.

Answer (score 1):

From the web view standpoint, there's no Node.js, no VS Code, node_modules or anything you have in the extension you are writing. The content of the web view must be fully self contained. You have to use a bundler (like webpack) to create JS bundles of your application you want to show in the web view, which includes all the source code of the referenced 3rd party libraries.